# $(this).removeattr('disabled') not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am using `$(this).removeattr('disabled')` to remove the checked attribute from a check box but it is not working in chrome. Can anyone help me for this?

I have also tried some other solution like -

1) `$(this).prop('checked', false)`

2)   `$(this).removeAttr('checked')`

3)   `$(this).attr('checked', false)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `removeAttr` and not `removeattr` as in your first example. But, why would removing the `disabled` attribute affect the checked attribute of the checkbox?

Comment: your *this* must be referring something wrong

Comment: You say it doesnt work in chrome. Does it work in another browser?

Comment: what is $(this) in your code, can you show some more of related code..?

Comment: Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery/426276#426276

Comment: Yes it is working in mozilla browser. Thanks for the comment. BUt as i found it is the problem of post. Actually i am using 3 step form - user submit informationa t first page and come to second page with the post array of first page then select some other field at second page and go to last step. Now if user come back on second page then the user get conflict in the post array of step 1 and step 2.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand difference between `"attr"` and `"prop"`

[Here's a user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr.), with the main part being:

> I'll summarize the main issues:
>
> - You usually want `prop()` rather than `attr()`.
> - In the majority of cases, `prop()` does what `attr()` used to do. Replacing calls to `attr()` with `prop()` in your code will generally
>     work.
> - Properties are generally simpler to deal with than attributes. An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any
>     type. For example, the `checked` property is a Boolean, the `style`
>     property is an object with individual properties for each style, the
>     `size` property is a number.
> - Where both a property and an attribute with the same name exists, usually updating one will update the other, but this is not the case
>     for certain attributes of inputs, such as `value` and `checked`: for
>     these attributes, the property always represents the current state
>     while the attribute (except in old versions of IE) corresponds to the
>     default value/checkedness of the input (reflected in the
>     `defaultValue` / `defaultChecked` property).
> - This change removes some of the layer of magic jQuery stuck in front of attributes and properties, meaning jQuery developers will have to
>     learn a bit about the difference between properties and attributes.
>     This is a good thing.

Now there is no function called `"removeattr"`, it should be `"removeAttr"`, this will work if you are using older version of jquery(i.e <1.5).

Since `checked` is the property of element so its **safe and correct** to use `.prop("checked",false)` to make working in all browser.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery/426276#426276) gets a bit more practical:

> ### jQuery 1.6+
>
> Use the new [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop) method:
>
> ```
> $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
> $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
> ```
>
> ### jQuery 1.5.x and below
>
> The `.prop()` method is not available, so you need to use
>   [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr).
>
> ```
> $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
> $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
> ```
>
> Note that this is [the approach used by jQuery's unit tests prior to
>   version 1.6](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.2/test/unit/attributes.js#L157) and is preferable to using
>
> ```
> $('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i am using jquery 10 and i have used both of the method already.

Comment: Yes it is working in mozilla browser. Thanks for the comment. BUt as i found it is the problem of post. Actually i am using 3 step form - user submit informationa t first page and come to second page with the post array of first page then select some other field at second page and go to last step. Now if user come back on second page then the user get conflict in the post array of step 1 and step 2. – Vipul Jain 19 secs ago